# iOS change specific cells in table view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

The function below starts the creation of cells from zero to n, with content retrieved from the model. I have a few cells in my table at the beginning which has static contents and I want function below ignore them and start from `n`th place to insert new data. How will I do that? In other words, how can I return an already-existing cell at `n`th place?

`- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

Comment: You can ignore desired cells inside - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath checking indexPath.section and indexPath.row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath` is needed for scrolling, as the tableView doesn't load all cells at once.

If you want to reload only a portion of your tableView you can use the method `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` or `reloadSections:withRowAnimation:`. This will reload only the specified cells.

If you have a performance problems, and don't want to load the static cells every time the tableView scrolls to them, you can store them in a property after they are created, and only return them. It would look somewhat like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    switch (indexPath.row) {
        case 0:
           //Static cell
           if (self.staticCell == nil) {
               self.staticCell = [UITableViewCell new]; //Instantiate properly here
               //Customize cell
           }
           return self.staticCell;
           break;
        case 1:
           // Other cells normally
           break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually I need to prevent changing first a few cells that I before fill some content but it seems I will refill them in this function with switch function.

Comment: If the cell is already created, it will only be returned in the method, it wont be changed at all. The method will only fill the cell if the property is nil. If its not nil its only returned.

Comment: Ok, I confused at reaching already created cells but we will define them as property. Now it is ok.

Answer (score 0):

In pseudo-code:

```
if (indexPath.row == 0)
    return some static cell;

else if (indexPath.row == 1)
    return some other static cell;

else
    configure cell N with data[N-2];
```

Comment: I have already these cells with some content so I do not want to return new one.